# Xslt - Move node to one "level" up

Tags: xslt

I want an xml attribute one level up in an xml structure.
As for requested I show a more detailed example:

```
<items>
  <kitchen>
    <furnitures>
      <chairs type="wood">
        <chair_1 color="green" legs="4"/>
      </chairs>
      <tables type="stone">
      </tables>
    </furnitures>
  </kitchen>
</items>
```

And I want to output this:

```
<items>
  <kitchen>
    <furnitures>
      <chairs type="wood"/>
      <chair_1 color="green" legs="4"/>
      <tables type="stone">
      </tables>
    </furnitures>
  </kitchen>
</items>
```

As you see I move char_1 to under  from under

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xls:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text()">
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/items/kitchen/furnitures/chairs">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="chair_1">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self:chair_1)]|@*|text()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="chair_1"/>
    </xsl:when>
     <!----- edit -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xls:apply-templates select ="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="settings"/>
       <xsl:text>
       </xsl:text>
       <chair_1 color="green" legs="4"/>
    </xls:otherwise>
  </xls:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

So, my main problem is, that my copy don't contain line-breaks.
Please keep in mind, I am using PHP:Xsltproc, on my dev-comp the indentation works fine, but with PHP's xsltproc it isn't fine, and drops the line breaks.
so the output like this:

```
<items>
  <kitchen>
    <furnitures>
      <chairs type="wood"/><chair_1 color="green" legs="4"/>
      <tables type="stone">
      </tables>
    </furnitures>
  </kitchen>
</items>
```

Which is fine, but not correctly indented.
(Disclaimer: there could be some typos, as this is not the original XML, and of course I am using the required stylsheet, version, phpversion, xml version tags, and of course my output method is xml and indent="yes" )

UPDATE:
when I have the second "WHEN", (in case there is no chair_1) I want to "paste" it into the code. But the indentation fails, it makes the whole copy into one line. What could be the problem?

Comment: `<color="green"...` is invalid. Did you mean `<chair color="green" ...` ?
Also, apart from a newline and a typo (`char`), it seems your actual and desired output are identical?

Comment: I understand you probably wanted to make a quick-and-dirty example, but it's more dirty than necessary. :) Can you please edit it to make it more clear, and fix the markup so that it's valid?

Comment: @msanford  I changed the original question. Probably it could be more readable, and I attached my original code.

Comment: @AttilaKis Thank you, that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templates you present do not effect the transformation you say they do, at least not by themselves.  In fact, they are not even valid XSL.

After the obvious syntax errors are corrected, the resulting template matching `node()` explicitly rearranges whitespace around elements (where it is not stripped) and does nothing effective at preserving attributes.  You seem to intend for it to be an identity transform, but the conventional identity transform goes like this:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Observe in particular that the `node()` test matches both elements and text nodes (and comments and processing instructions), but not attributes, and that if you do not want to rearrange an element's text nodes relative to its child elements then you must transform them all via the same `xsl:apply-templates` directive.

Additionally, do note that in many XML applications, whitespace-only runs of text separating tags are insignificant.  I don't see any reason to think that your particular application is among the exceptions, so you really ought to ask yourself is "does it matter?"

Supposing that it does matter -- e.g. because you want improved human readability even though the XML is primarily meant to be consumed by a computer program that doesn't care about the indentation -- you should consider letting your XSL processor provide indentation for you.  To do this, start by *stripping* all the insignificant whitespace from the input document:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

and follow up by asking the processor to provide hierarchical indentation for you:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

Both of those directives have global effect, and they need to appear as direct children of the `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` element.  Here's the cleaned up and updated version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/items/kitchen/furnitures/chairs">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="chair_1">
        <xsl:copy>
          <!-- also simplified the 'select' expression below: -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::chair_1)]|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="chair_1"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        BUNCH of code there if we don't have chair_1
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Work great, thanks! I have a small another question, I edited the original question. In summary: when I have the second "WHEN", (in case there is no chair_1) I want to "paste" it into the code. But the indentation fails, it makes the whole copy into one line. Do you know, what could be  the problem?

Comment: @AttilaKis, indentation performed automatically by the processor as I suggested operates on *elements*, not on text.  In fact, the whole idea is premised on the supposition that the indentation to be provided will be interpreted as insignificant whitespace by consumers of the XML result.  Any indentation you introduce into text, especially text that is not all whitespace, is *significant* to most processors.  Nevertheless, if you want to manually insert indentation then you should be able to just wrap your indented text in an `xsl:text` element.